# Java SE or Java EE (standard or enterprise)?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java

I'm starting to do a lot of Java EE dev work. Is it ok to install Java EE on my home machine instead of a JRE?

Also, can GlassFish run on a JRE or does it need Java EE?

Answer (score 7):

Java EE is an abstract API. GlassFish is one of the available concrete Java EE implementations. The Java EE download from Oracle.com is basically just GlassFish along with some documentation/examples and optionally also NetBeans. So if you download Java EE from Oracle.com, you've already GlassFish :)

It only requires a Java SE JDK (not *just* JRE!) already on your machine which has to be downloaded and installed separately. If you intend to develop with JSF, you may find [this tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html) useful as well. It covers installing JDK, GlassFish and Eclipse from the zero beginning in detail.

#### See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165230/is-the-offical-sun-java-ee-tutorial-the-best-way-to-learn-how-to-make-java-web-ap

Answer (score 1):

You still need a JRE (Java Runtime Environment).  Actually, you really need a JDK (Java Development Kit) so you can compile.

GlashFish includes the Java EE libraries.  It runs on a JRE or JDK.  If you are using JSPs, you have to run GlassFish against a JDK (because JSP technology does code generation/compilation at run-time.

Comment: Wow.  I must be really tired.  Of course I meant a JDK.  I've known that forever :).  I'll edit my incorrect comment for clarity.