# Can't find jsp on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, jsp

I am using the last version of Eclipse 3.7.
I am working with the Google app engine and need to create some JSP, but on a new project. I can't find JSP.
I don't have Tomcat.
Can I just do `new->file` and then just end it with `.jsp`, like `filename.jsp`?

Will it be okay?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Google App Engine, but to have ability to run project with JSP files you should create a web project.

I don't know which plugin in eclise you're using, but [this tutorial](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse.html#Creating_a_Project) looks easy, try it:

> 1. Select the File menu > New > Web Application Project
> 2. The "Create a Web Application Project" wizard opens. For "Project
>      name," enter a name for your project,
> 3. If you're not using Google Web Toolkit, uncheck "Use Google Web
>      Toolkit." Verify that "Use Google App Engine" is checked.
> 4. If you installed the App Engine SDK using Software Update, the
>      plugin is already configured to use the SDKs that were installed. If
>      you would like to use a separate installation of the App Engine SDK,
>      click Configure SDKs..., and follow the prompts to add a configuration
>      with your SDK's appengine-java-sdk/ directory.
> 5. Click Finish to create the project.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file with a .jsp extension in your war directory (or a non-WEB-INF/ subdirectory). Works fine. (I'm using Eclipse 3.6 with SDK 1.5.4.)

Comment: I disagree, all files in WEB-INF are hidden to the end user.

Comment: Yeah, that was a stupid mistake. Thanks for pointing it out. Fixed above. I blame the lack of coffee :-P

Answer (score 1):

To use JSP, you need to download the [J2EE SDK](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/) from Oracle and the [Eclipse IDE For EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) in order to access JSP pages from Eclipse. See [Eclipse Docs](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user/topics/tjcrejsp.html), [Eclipse Web Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/), and [this forum post](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?317285-developing-jsp-in-eclipse). There's a wealth of information out there.

To develop and test locally, you will need a web server, such as [Apache's Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) or [JBOSS](http://www.jboss.org/), both of which are available for free. Otherwise, you'd have to upload the file to Google App Engine, look at it, debug it, take it down, and repeat the process until you're done development.

Comment: You don't **need** J2EE SDK if you're choosing Tomcat or JBoss. This is a common misconception among starters. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999104/jse-or-jee-standard-or-enterprise/5999143#5999143 Just Eclipse for Java EE and the GAE plugin is sufficient.

Comment: True, you could add the server to the project build path which would include all the J2EE libraries. It'd still be helpful to have the EE IDE though, if you go that route, so you get access to the internal javadoc and such. If you don't want to mess with running your own server, you need the SDK though.

Comment: Java EE SDK contains Glassfish+Netbeans. It's only useful if you want both.

Comment: You can choose not to install either during the installation process.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install Eclipse Web Developer Tools (3.15) and the jsp file type was visible. Just open the Eclipse Marketplace from Eclipse and find this extension.